# How to counter Kennen toplane?

Tags: league-of-legends

i like to play Top and normaly win almost every lane. I just have Problems wit h handling Kennen(ad and ap). Very early in the game he just e out of the engage and autohit you, even with a gapcloser you almost always get more dmg then you deal.
Later he just always stuns you when you engage.

I know that yorick is pretty god against him i just dont like him, so how o beat him with other champs?

Would be nice if someone has an idea, i guess it will helps other players, too cause i almost never saw him loose a lane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kennen simply is strong cause he is ranged. The problem when laning against Kennen aswell is, that your jungler cant really help you, cause Kennen can escape about 80% of the ganks.

One thing you can do is pick another ranged top against him (Vlad, Jayce, Nida), the problem here is that he either outscales them (nida, jayce) or beats them early (vlad). 
You can also go with a very very tanky champ, preferebly a champ who has a shield (Malph, Udyr, Riven) and just ignore his early AA damage. 
The third and last thing you can do is get a stronger late game champ (Jax, Irelia), go for 1 or 2 gp10 and just farm as much as you can. The good thing about these champs is, that they can beat a Kennen after 5 min alraedy if they get one succesfull gank of (or they get a kill from another lane).

What you have to remember is, that Kennens main advantage is his AA range and his snowballing cause of early dominance. Start cloth 5 if the enemy has a weak early jungler (Skarner, Mundo, WW), go for a Ninja Tabi if his AA are killing you really hard (even tho I wouldn't do that often, Mercs are simply better against his CC) and dont go for all the creeps early. If you have to take 3 or 4 Autoattacks, just to get 1 or 2 cs, its definitly not worth it. Try to passivly farm as much as possible and stay on more than 50% HP. As Irelia, you can sneak some CS with your Q till you get to lvl 6 and got 2 dorans or a phage, then you can beat him pretty hard. What you can do as a meele Bruiser is get some early MR and ninja tabi, and then just go for gp10 and late game.

EDIT: Most people know this, but they dont do it: Stay behind minions and dodge his Q. He will probably max Q, so if you manage to dodge it, you avoid 100-300 dmg early game.

Comment: ok i think i just have to practice, cause i tryed to beat him with irelia and i just failed. I first jump him but he often hit his q cause i stand so close to him and the he activate e and press w, so i am stuned, i just got 1 q and 1 autohit on him. I maybe just have to dodge the q but its not so easy if you engage and if you just stay passive he will have more cs and maybe he gets your tower early...

Comment: true, but if he pushes your tower he will get ganked, and loosing cs against Kennen is better than dying to him... If you want to harass him, wait till he uses either his W passive (every 4th attack), till he lasthits with his Q or till he uses his E to push the lane. If one or more of these things are not ready, you can jump on him! 

When playing irelia remember to activate your W before using Q (Q procs one AA, if you have W active you deal ~70 true dmg + the Q dmg)

Comment: Yeah i not that about Irelia. The Problem when he pushs me is that my jungler is 4 of 5 times not in the postion to do anything or he is just blind, so i dont want to rely on ganks.

Comment: Thats soloq, you have little to no impact on that. Ask (kind!) as soon as kennen pushes and then just try to lane.

Answer (score 0):

On Bruiser tops I rush double null-magic mantle after starting boots and pots.  One is to go into Merc treads and the other into Wit's End or Hexdrinker.

Generally these 2 items give me enough defense to either stay in lane and farm or go counter aggressive against an AP Kennen.  If you let him get ahead early with kill there may be no way to get back ahead without a lot of jungle help.

Comment: But dont you think that you should never start without boots? Its way to easy to gank you and you can dodge or run away from the other laner if needed.  The other problem should be that you have less potions and early kennen autohit more then throw q. Dont you think so?

Comment: Yes I start boots 4 pots and get double null-magic as soon as possible

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Also early pressure from jungler works very well and one great thing is amplify toplane with redbuff. Kennen must change more hits when hit.

Solotop vlad beats kennen imo pretty much and swain do very well too.

Comment: Yeah i thought about vlad aswell.. I just still have to buy him -.-  I may keep ip for him.
I think the Problem with swain may be that he has no real escape and I am not going to lie if I say that i get ganked pretty often and i dont want that to own me even harder

Answer (score 0):

Best counter to [Kennen](http://www.picklol.net/kennen) are: Ryze, Kass, Swain, Leblanc and Yorik.

1. Ryze can stun him and let a lot of dmg.
2. Kass can escape from his ulti.
3. Swain can stun + lot of dmg

Answer (score 0):

If he goes AD, your goal is to simply not feed him.  He falls off late game so as long as he's not really ahead, you don't have to worry about much.